# Realm database, add a arraylist of objects as a column for a class

Tags: android, database, migration, database-migration, realm

I worked with migration so far, using the example from Realm. 
And for adding a simple column I would do something like:

```
Table personTable = realm.getTable(Trip.class);
long vehicleIndex = personTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "vehicle");
```

BUT now I need to add an arraylist like this one to the object:

```
 private ArrayList<StopInfo> filteredLocations = new ArrayList<>();
```

How can I rezolve this migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in Realm, if you want to have a list field, [RealmList](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html) is the thing to use. See [doc](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#many-to-many).

Second, to add a RealmList in your migration:

Assume you have `RealmList<StopInfo>` defined in your Model class

```java
private RealmList<StopInfo> stopInfoList;
```

To add it in the migration:

```java
// In the Migration
// Create RealmList field
long listIndex = table.addColumnLink(ColumnType.LINK_LIST,
    "stopInfoList", transaction.getTable("class_StopInfo"));
```

Comment: class_StopInfo from gettable is made with the form class_ClassName?
Ex: Class Test -> transaction.getTable("class_Test")

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Implementing this now